# Akka with spring and maven

Tags: spring, maven, akka

I am trying to use "Akka" model with spring in maven project but i am not able to succeed because i am getting initialization failed error. I would like to know that is it possible to use them together and if it is then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, we built a whole framework based on akka+spring+maven at my company. Setting it up is a bit tricky, but once configured it works smoothly. You can find a lot of examples online, like http://www.baeldung.com/akka-with-spring, but just by googling 'akka spring example' you will get a few entries.